# Play Button Disappeared From Netflix in Windows 7 Media Center

Tags: windows-7, media-center, netflix

For the last year and a half I've enjoyed watching Netflix movies in Windows 7 Media Center. Within the last few days I've encountered a problem where the play button no longer shows up reliably. I can open my instant queue, select a movie or episode, get the information, but not play it. If I browse around my queue I may eventually get a movie that has a play button. After watching the movie, however, the play button may disappear.

This appears to be a recent problem as shown by threads in other less helpful forums around the webternet:

- http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3429337
- http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110805161821AA6cW04
- http://experts.windows.com/frms/windows_entertainment_and_connected_home/f/114/p/101709/542671.aspx

I can't find anything on Netflix's support site about this. It seems as though this may be a problem with an update or someting. Any hints?

Comment: Seems to be affecting everyone - very annoying. I found that pressing CTRL+SHIFT+P will allow you to play it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem from Microsoft, calling Netflix technical support will get you punted to Microsoft technical support as they created the plugin for Windows Media Center. New real information can be obtained from contact technical support, however.

As per @[Rachel](https://superuser.com/users/93201/rachel)'s comment, you can still hit CTRL+SHIFT+P to play videos. Likewise, if you're using a IR remote control you can hit the "Play" button on the remote and it will place regardless of whether or not the play button is visible.